# Cannot install anything because of /usr/local/ permission

Tags: catalina, bash, install, homebrew

I'm using OS Catalina atm. I am trying to install Node and Homebrew but I can't seem to install anything because it keeps on saying I don't have permission in `/usr/local/`

Installing homebrew gives me

```
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/local/share/zsh: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions: Operation not permitted
Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod 755 /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```

I tried changing permissions via `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/*` but I keep on getting `Operation not permitted`

Some people suggested to reinstall homebrew but I can't do it because of the permissions so I am just running in circles. I can't install anything too like Virtual env or any other apps.

Please help!!!

I also tried reinstall my mac os but still no luck :(

Comment: Does  /usr/local exist and what is in it. Try `ls -lR /usr/local` You possibly have a mixed up system after changes/

Comment: yes it exists. I tried running the command and the owners are mixed up either "myusername" or "postgres"

Comment: You have installed other programs in /usr/local/bin (including postgres) You can really only use Homebrew if you have nothing else installed in /usr/local/bin  You need to uninstall the other programs before using Homebrew

Comment: so in this case it's postgresql right?

Comment: At least try that first